# Can AWS Lightsail Container be used with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, containers, mongodb-atlas, amazon-lightsail

I've been looking at running a simple Docker container based website on AWS Lightsail for simplicity and would like to put the database on the MongoDB Atlas service rather than use AWS DynamoDB because the latter is only MongoDB compatible (3.6) and is more expensive.

MongoDB Atlas' security measures allow us to provide IP address ranges to restrict who can access the database, but Lightsail only provides static IPs for Instances, not for Containers. We don't want to open up Atlas for public access by any IP.

So my questions are:

- Can you get a static IP or range of IPs for the container running in AWS Lightsail?
- If not, can you create a Lightsail Load Balancer for the containers and use a static IP for that?

If none of this is possible, the next best option seems to be to use an AWS EC2 instance for the container with Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions:

- Get Static IP for Containers running in LightSail - Not Possible
- Get IP of Load Balancer in LightSail - Not Possible

But instead of going to EC2 instance to run your container, you can use LightSail instance (OS Only) and run your container there.